# If insert row fails skip

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I know that I am just missing something on this but I am trying to upsert data via a LWC from a CSV. Currently I am getting an error since we have duplicate rules turned on. All I am trying to do is if that record already exist, it will move on to the next row to insert. What am I missing?

Controller:

```
public class lwcCSVUploaderController {

@AuraEnabled
public static List<Lead> saveFile(String base64Data) {
    String data    = JSON.deserializeUntyped(base64Data).toString();
    Integer TotalCreated = 0;
    list<Lead> lstCCToUpsert = new list<Lead>();
    list<String> lstCSVLines = data.split('\n');
    list<Lead> dupeList = [Select ID, Email, FirstName, LastName from Lead where Email !=null];

    for(Integer i = 1; i < lstCSVLines.size(); i++){
        Lead ld = new Lead();
        String csvLine = lstCSVLines[i];
        String prevLine = csvLine;
        Integer startIndex;
        Integer endIndex;
        
        while(csvLine.indexOf('"') > -1){
            if(startIndex == null){
                startIndex = csvLine.indexOf('"');
                csvLine = csvLine.substring(0, startIndex) + ':quotes:' + csvLine.substring(startIndex+1, csvLine.length());
            }else{
                if(endIndex == null){
                    endIndex = csvLine.indexOf('"');
                    csvLine = csvLine.substring(0, endIndex) + ':quotes:' + csvLine.substring(endIndex+1, csvLine.length());
                }
            }
            
            if(startIndex != null && endIndex != null){
                String sub = csvLine.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
                sub = sub.replaceAll(',', ':comma:');
                csvLine = csvLine.substring(0, startIndex) + sub + csvLine.substring(endIndex, csvLine.length());
                startIndex = null;
                endIndex = null;
            }
        }
        
        List<String> csvRowData = new List<String>();

        for(String column : csvLine.split(',')){
            column = column.replaceAll(':quotes:', '').replaceAll(':comma:', ',');
            csvRowData.add(column);
        }

        ld.FirstName                      = csvRowData[0];
        ld.LastName                       = csvRowData[1];
        ld.Title                          = csvRowData[2];
        ld.Company                        = csvRowData[3];
        ld.Email                          = csvRowData[4];
        ld.Street                         = csvRowData[5];
        ld.City                           = csvRowData[6];
        ld.State                          = csvRowData[7];
        ld.PostalCode                     = csvRowData[8];
        ld.Industry                       = csvRowData[9];
        ld.Phone                          = csvRowData[10];
        ld.LeadSource                     = csvRowData[11];
        ld.Headquartered_State__c         = csvRowData[12];
        ld.Managing_Director__c           = csvRowData[13];
        ld.Store_Industry__c              = csvRowData[14];
        ld.Industry_Sector__c             = csvRowData[15];
        ld.Ownerid                        = '00G79000000YwYyEAK';
        
            for(Lead newLeads !:dupeList){
                lstCCToUpsert.add(ld);

    }

        //upsert lstCCToUpsert;

    return [Select Id, 
                   FirstName, 
                   LastName, 
                   Company, 
                   Title, 
                   Email,
                   Street, 
                   City, 
                   State, 
                   PostalCode, 
                   Industry, 
                   Phone, 
                   Headquartered_State__c,
                   Managing_Director__c,
                   Store_Industry__c,
                   Industry_Sector__c
                From Lead 
                Where Id in :lstCCToUpsert
            ];
}
}
```

JS

```
        import { LightningElement, track, api } from 'lwc';
        import saveFile from '@salesforce/apex/lwcCSVUploaderController.saveFile';
        import {ShowToastEvent} from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';

        const columns = [

        { label: 'First Name', fieldName: 'FirstName' },
        { label: 'Last Name', fieldName: 'LastName' },
        { label: 'Title', fieldName: 'Title' },
        { label: 'Company', fieldName: 'Company' },
        { label: 'Email', fieldName: 'Email' },
        { label: 'Street', fieldName: 'Street' },
        { label: 'City', fieldName: 'City' },
        { label: 'State', fieldName: 'State' },
        { label: 'Zip Code', fieldName: 'PostalCode' },
        { label: 'Industry', fieldName: 'Industry' },
        { label: 'Phone', fieldName: 'Phone' }

        ];

        export default class LwcCSVUploader extends LightningElement {

        @api recordid;
        @track columns = columns;
        @track data;
        @track fileName = '';
        @track a
        @track UploadFile = 'Upload CSV File';
        @track showLoadingSpinner = false;
        @track isTrue = false;
        selectedRecords;
        filesUploaded = [];
        file;
        fileContents;
        fileReader;
        content;
        MAX_FILE_SIZE = 1500000;

        handleFilesChange(event) {

            if(event.target.files.length > 0) {
                this.filesUploaded = event.target.files;
                this.fileName = event.target.files[0].name;
            }
        }

        handleSave() {
            if(this.filesUploaded.length > 0) {
                this.uploadHelper();
            }
            else {
                this.fileName = 'Please select a CSV file to upload!!';
            }
        }

        uploadHelper() {
            this.file = this.filesUploaded[0];
            if (this.file.size > this.MAX_FILE_SIZE) {
                window.console.log('File Size is to long');
                return ;
            }

            this.showLoadingSpinner = true;
            this.fileReader= new FileReader();
            this.fileReader.onloadend = (() => {
                this.fileContents = this.fileReader.result;
                this.saveToFile();
            });

            this.fileReader.readAsText(this.file);
        }

        saveToFile() {
            saveFile({ base64Data: JSON.stringify(this.fileContents), cdbId: this.recordid})
            .then(result => {
                window.console.log('result ====> ');
                window.console.log(result);
                this.data = result;
                this.fileName = this.fileName + ' - Uploaded Successfully';
                this.isTrue = false;
                this.showLoadingSpinner = false;
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Success!!',
                        message: this.file.name + ' - Uploaded Successfully!!!',
                        variant: 'success',
                    }),
                );
            })
            .catch(error => {
                window.console.log(error);
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Error while uploading File',
                        message: error.message,
                        variant: 'error',
                    }),
                );
            });
        }
        }
```

Template

```
        <template>
            
            <template if:true={showLoadingSpinner}>
                <div style="z-index: 10000 !important;">
                    <lightning-spinner alternative-text="Uploading......" size="medium" style="z-index: 10000 !important;"></lightning-spinner>
                </div>
            </template>

            <lightning-card title="Process CSV File">

                <div style="margin-left:4%; margin:0px auto; width: 300px;">
                    <div>
                        <lightning-input label="" name="file uploader" onchange   ={handleFilesChange} type="file" multiple></lightning-input>
                    </div><br/>
                    <div class="slds-text-body_small slds-text-color_error">{fileName}

                    </div><br/>
                    <div>
                        <lightning-button class="slds-m-top--medium" label={UploadFile} onclick  ={handleSave} variant="brand" disabled={isTrue}></lightning-button>
                    </div>
                </div><br/><br/>


            </lightning-card>
            
            <lightning-card title="Leads" icon-name="standard:lead">
                <div style="width: auto;">
                    <template if:true={data}>
                            <lightning-datatable
                                    data={data}
                                    columns={columns}
                                    key-field="id">
                            </lightning-datatable>
                    </template>
                </div>
            </lightning-card>



        </template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the alternative Database.upsert method:

```
Database.UpsertResult[] results = Database.upsert(lstCCToUpsert, false);
```

The second parameter, `false`, allows a partial success. You can parse the results array to determine which records failed, in case you want to report errors to the user.

Also, having very recently done a CSV parser myself, I recommend parsing the CSV on the client, converting that CSV into an array of objects:

```
[
  { sobjectType: 'Lead',
    FirstName: 'Brian',
    LastName: 'Fear',
    Email: 'donotreply@salesforce.com',
    // ... etc
  },
  // ... etc
]
```

Then, you can change your Apex code to just:

```
public class Result {
  @AuraEnabled public Boolean success { get; set; }
  @AuraEnabled public String error { get; set; }
}
@AuraEnabled public static Result[] saveFile(Lead[] records) {
  Database.UpsertResult[] results = Database.upsert(records, false);
  // Do error handling here
}
```